# How do I replace <span * style="font-weight:bold;">*</span> with <strong>*</strong> with PHP preg_replace?

Tags: php, html, regex

Attempting regex on a HTML file with the following code:

```
<body style=""><p class="Normal" style="direction:ltr;unicode-bidi:normal;"><span class="Normal-H"><span class="-H" style="font-weight:bold;"></span><span class="-H" style="font-weight:bold;">Some bold text</span></span></p><p class="Normal" style="direction:ltr;unicode-bidi:normal;"><span class="Normal-H"><span class="-H" style="font-style:italic;"></span><span class="-H" style="font-style:italic;">Some italic text</span></span></p></body></html>
```

Note the `<span class="-H" style="font-weight:bold;">Some bold text</span>`

I am currently using PHP `preg_replace` `'/<span class="-H" style="font-style:italic;">(.*?)<\/span>/'`, to replace as `<strong>Some bold text</strong>`however this is limited to `spans` with the class `"-H"`

How might I replace **any** instance of `<span>` that includes the attribute `style="font-weight:bold;"` with `<strong>Bold text</strong>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RegEx should be:

```
%^(<span(.*?)style="font-weight:bold;"(.*?)>(.*?)</span>)$% // % is the delimeter.
```

You should place the the text into strong tag like this:

```
<strong>$4</strong>
```

Tested at http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

```
$text = '<span class="-H" style="font-weight:bold;">Some bold text</span>';
$regex = '%^(<span(.*?)style="font-weight:bold;"(.*?)>(.*?)</span>)$%';
$replace = '<strong>$4</strong>';
echo preg_replace($regex, $replace, $text);
```

Comment: Thanks onatm - works great, have modified slightly for my exact requirements and other use cases

Answer (score 3):

a regex could be very difficult. but what about this solution?

```
$element = simplexml_load_string('<span class="-H" style="font-weight:bold;">Some boldtext</span>');
$attributes = $element->attributes();

echo strpos($attributes->class, ':') ? strstr($attributes->class, ':', false) : $attributes->class;
echo $element;
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, have opted for onatm's solution but will bear yours in mind for future scenarios

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a RegEx, you can use a DOM parser, like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), to replace the correct `<span>` tags with `<strong>` tags.  It might be easier to use/adapt than a RegEx.

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML('<body style=""><p class="Normal" style="direction:ltr;unicode-bidi:normal;"><span class="Normal-H"><span class="-H" style="font-weight:bold;"></span><span class="-H" style="font-weight:bold;">Some bold text</span></span></p><p class="Normal" style="direction:ltr;unicode-bidi:normal;"><span class="Normal-H"><span class="-H" style="font-style:italic;"></span><span class="-H" style="font-style:italic;">Some italic text</span></span></p></body></html>');
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$spans = $xPath->query('//span');
foreach($spans as $span){
  if($span->hasAttribute('style')){
    if(strstr($span->getAttribute('style'), 'font-weight:bold') !== FALSE){
      $newSpan = $dom->createElement('strong', $span->nodeValue);
      $span->parentNode->replaceChild($newSpan, $span);
    }
  }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/bIyAlXUf

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can get appropriate result which has given below,

```
$text    = '<span class="-H" style="font-weight:bold;">Some bold text</span>';
$regex   = '/<span(.*?)style="font-weight:bold;"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/span>/gi'; //if you use only first 
$replace = '<strong>$4</strong>';
echo preg_replace($regex, $replace, $text);
```