# replace <span> elements with strong

Tags: php, regex

I would like to replace all `<span>` elements containing the attribute `font-weight:` with `<strong>` elements.

I am using the following regex

```
$text = preg_replace("@<span (.*?)style=(.*?)font-weight:(.*?)>(.*?)</span>@i", "<strong>$4</strong>", $text);
```

that is a little variation of the solution proposed by onatm here: [How do I replace <span * style="font-weight:bold;">*</span> with <strong>*</strong> with PHP preg_replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903813/how-do-i-replace-span-style-font-weightbold-span-with-strong-stro)

Unfortunately this regex delete from the $text string all  element that do not contain the `font-weight:` attribute. This is something I do not want. My goal is to replace only the spans that contain font-weight: and leave without change any other element.

I have created a live example here: https://onlinephp.io/c/c0b92

How can the problem be solved ?

Thank you for your help :)

**Edit**:
by playing a bit with it I managed to achieve my goal by using

```
@<span [^>]*style=[^>]*font-weight:[^>]*>(.*?)</span>@i
```

The DOM solution proposed does not work. I am still interested in understanding how to proper implement it

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML, it's not the right tool. Have a look at [DomDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) - [More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I know, but i would like to do it in this way for simplicity. I simply do not understand why other span elements disappear. Any help is kindly appreciated

Comment: Because using `.*` is *greedy*

Comment: Please don't post solutions inside the question. Because of your edited question: the (AI-generated) answer is definitely working as well - [demo](https://ideone.com/xHiZvD)